# Groupby sum based on some condition on sequence of other column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data frame shown below.

Note that we have only F-P-F pattern. ie our data only will have F-P-F pattern.

```
    ID  Status  Date    Duration
0   1   F   2018-06-22  nan
1   1   P   2018-08-22  61.00
2   1   F   2018-10-22  61.00
3   3   F   2018-11-20  nan
4   3   P   2018-12-20  30.00
5   3   F   2019-03-20  90.00
6   4   F   2018-06-10  nan
7   4   P   2018-08-10  61.00
8   4   F   2018-12-10  122.00
9   7   F   2018-04-10  nan
10  7   P   2018-08-10  122.00
11  7   F   2018-11-10  92.00
12  7   P   2019-08-10  273.00
13  7   F   2019-10-10  61.00
```

From the above data frame I would like to prepare below data frame.

```
ID        F_P_Duration    F_F_Duration                          
1         61.0            122.0
3         30.0            120.0
4         61.0            183.0
7_1       122.0           214.0
7_2       273.0           334.0
```

where F_P_Duration is number of days from F to P

F_F_Duration is number of days from F to F in F-P-F pattern of that ID

Comment: Can you explain what your intention was? And show a shorter example with detailed steps that should happen?

Comment: @eumiro updated, am I able to explain correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are either just taking the duration from one row, or summing with the previous, depending on the ID column. The real trickery comes in the arranging and labeling. I think the code below should be pretty self-explanatory.

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Setup the data and the DataFrame.
data = [[1, 'F', '2018-06-22', np.nan],
        [1, 'P', '2018-08-22', 61.00],
        [1, 'F', '2018-10-22', 61.00],
        [3, 'F', '2018-11-20', np.nan],
        [3, 'P', '2018-12-20', 30.00],
        [3, 'F', '2019-03-20', 90.00],
        [4, 'F', '2018-06-10', np.nan],
        [4, 'P', '2018-08-10', 61.00],
        [4, 'F', '2018-12-10', 122.00],
        [7, 'F', '2018-04-10', np.nan],
        [7, 'P', '2018-08-10', 122.00],
        [7, 'F', '2018-11-10', 92.00],
        [7, 'P', '2019-08-10', 273.00],
        [7, 'F', '2019-10-10', 61.00]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['ID', 'Status', 'Date', 'Duration'])

# Add a helper column for summing F_F durations.
df['DurShiftSum'] = df['Duration'] + df['Duration'].shift(1)
# F_P duration just appears to be the duration at P.
df.loc[df['Status']=='P', 'F_P_Duration'] = df.loc[df['Status']=='P', 'Duration']
# F_F durations is the F duration plus the previous P duration.
df.loc[(df['Status']=='F')&(df['Duration'].notnull()), 'F_F_Duration'] = 
df.loc[(df['Status']=='F')&(df['Duration'].notnull()), 'DurShiftSum']
# Compress the DataFrame and drop unneeded columns.
df['F_F_Duration'] = df['F_F_Duration'].fillna(method='bfill', limit=1)
df = df.dropna(subset=['F_P_Duration'])
df = df.drop(labels=['Date', 'Duration', 'DurShiftSum'], axis=1)

# An unfortunate for-loop through the unique IDs.
# If your dataset is very big this might not be ideal.
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(str)
for xid in df['ID'].unique():
    if len(df.loc[df['ID']==xid]) > 1:
        len_frame = len(df.loc[df['ID']==xid])
        new_ids = [xid+f'_{i}' for i in range(1, len_frame+1)]
        df.loc[df['ID']==xid, 'ID'] = new_ids
```

I get a match to your desired results given the sample data you've provided. All I do is create a helper column that sums two adjacent rows, transfer appropriate values to the F_P and F_F columns, then clean up and format.